# Data not visible in mongoDB when inserted from PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to insert data in a mongodb collection from python but the data is not being logged. This is how I am doing it:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import time


class data2db:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def enter_data(self,data):
        client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', 27017)
        db = client.db
        coll=db.Temperature1
        post = {"auth": data ,
            "Time" : time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))}
        post_= coll.insert(post)


c=data2db()

c.enter_data("24.3")
```

When I try to access the data from another method it returns null. This how I do it:

```
client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', 27017)

db = client.db

coll=db.Temperature1

print coll.find_one({"_id" : 1})

print coll.find()

listed=str(coll.find({"_id" : 1})).split(' ')

listed=listed[len(listed)-1].split('>')[0]

listed={"_id" : "ObjectID(\""+listed+"\")"}

print coll.find_one(listed)'''

print db.command("collstats", "events")
```

As you can see, I already tried it in different ways but no matter what, it returns null. If I try to access the dbstats, like this:

```
print db.command("dbstats")
```

I get:

```
{u'extentFreeList': {u'totalSize': 0, u'num': 0}, u'storageSize': 49152, u'ok': 1.0, u'avgObjSize': 64.90566037735849, u'dataFileVersion': {u'major': 4, u'minor': 5}, u'db': u'db', u'indexes': 4, u'objects': 53, u'collections': 6, u'fileSize': 67108864, u'numExtents': 6, u'dataSize': 3440, u'indexSize': 32704, u'nsSizeMB': 16}
```

THe collection is not even showing on mongo commandline. Desperate for help.

Comment: I've copied your first file, and executed it. It inserted the data for me. (python2.7, mongo3.0.1). In your first file, would you be able to add "print post_" and see what the result is ? It should return you the id of the document inserted. (if it is successful)

Comment: I already checked that. it's returning a document contents but the collection is still missing. I am having a terrible time :'( I also checked my mongo version for compliance but this is going no where

Comment: @WanBachtiar is the collection Temperature1 available in your mongodb? If yes can you please check if db.Temperture1.find() returns anything? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Yes the collection is available. I can check using python "print list(coll.find())" and it returns me back the document. Im using Linux Mint. I think try to go back to basic, do the insert in mongo shell and see if it works there.

Comment: MongoShell and mongojava are working just fine. I particularly need python because I am using a API for a use case which ist python. Anyway the problem was finally resolved but now there's another problem, but when I post {"Temperature" : 24.3} and send a query, mongo returns {"_id": ObjectId("558019749f43b8c19779c106"),"Temperature" : -0.00000789320} Can you guess what the problem is? Integers like 12 are working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code "works' but I think you may have copied-and-pasted something wrong.  In particular, you're swapping the use of find() and find_one().

The enter_data() method calls insert() without specifying _id so the driver will invent one for you.  That _id ends up being an ObjectId similar to this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558019749f43b8c19779c106"), "auth" : "24.3", "Time" : "Tue Jun 16 08:41:24 2015" }
```

Your code later calls `print coll.find_one({"_id" : 1})` which will yield null because the invented _id will not be 1.

`find()` does not return a record; it returns a cursor.   Calling print does not print the contents. Try this instead:

```
for r in coll.find():
    print r
```

Lastly, because db is special convenience variable in the CLI, I'd avoid naming a database `db`.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I've already tried all of this but no matter what, the collection is not visible from mongo command line. :/

Comment: I tried:                                                                                                       for r in coll.find():
    print r                                                                                                            It's printing multiple documents to the console which is the desired behaviour. However, these same document and the collection Temperature1 is not visible when I check it by launching mongo. Is this how it's intended to work?

Comment: Launch mongo and do this:   use db      then    show collections

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again but when I post {"Temperature" : 24.3} and send a query, mongo returns {"_id": ObjectId("558019749f43b8c19779c106"),"Temperature" : -0.00000789320} Can you guess what the problem is? Integers like 12 are working fine

Comment: There is something going on with that "post."    Integers tend to be well behaved; floating point numbers and to- and from-string conversion in different languages can have oddments.   Long story short, we know MongoDB can save and fetch floating point numbers across languages, so it must be something in your code.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using a RaspberryPi for all this. Could it be that the floating point support for RaspberryPi is the limitation here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908471/pymongo-misbehaving-with-floating-point-numbers