# PyMongo misbehaving with floating point numbers

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, raspbian, database

I am using PyMongo to save data to a MongoDB. THe following is my code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import time


class data2db:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def enter_data(self, data):
        client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', 27017)
        db = client.db
        coll = db.Temperature1
        post = {"auth": data,
                "Time": time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))}
        post_ = coll.insert(post)


c = data2db()

c.enter_data(24.3)
```

However, when I retrieve this object I get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558019749f43b8c19779c106"), "auth" : -0.000063384, "Time" : "Tue Jun 16 08:41:24 2015" }
```

When I try the same code with integers it is working fine. I am using MongoDB 2.6.3 on RaspberryPi with the latest version of Raspbian and python 2.7.3. I installed Pymongo from the Raspbian repository, via this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pymongo
```

Can someone please help me out?

Update:
The same code behaves perfectly on an intel computer using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, mongoDB 3.0.1, python 2.7.3 and pyMongo 2.8 but when it comes to Raspbian the behaviour changes. Even in the mongo shell floating point insertions on Raspbian are misbehaving. It may be because of limited floating point support or a deprecated mongoDB version (The binaries for the latest version are not available for ARM). In anycase I'll try it with rpi2 later today and check it makes a difference or not.

Comment: In the first code segment the last line is: c.enter_data(24.3) not  c.enter_data("24.3")

Comment: In that case, how does the float `24.3` become the string `"-0.000063384"`, highly improbable this isn't due to some human mistake somewhere

Comment: I am using two different computers one for development and the other for internet and I wrote the object myself. I should have proof read it before posting here

Comment: In anycase I've revised the question, Thankyou for pointing that out

Comment: Could the problem be with lack of floating point support?

Comment: Added some notes to how to find out, I'm curious to find out the answer as well

Comment: Well I have a RaspberryPi2 at home, I'll check the same problem out with it when I get back home from work. Will post it here if it works out. I really appreciate your concern. Regards and respect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the insert is working fine but when queried it returns the object in wrong format. When I insert a float from rpi to a remote database then it works just fine. When the object is queried on the computer it was posted to it is displayed as it should be:

```
`{ "_id" : ObjectId("557d828b08139add2323aeaf"), "A" : 12.1 }`
```

but when queried from rpi it displays as:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557d828b08139add2323aeaf"), "A" : 0.04667261646131403e-60 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this

> c.enter_data("24.3")
>
> post = {"auth": data, ... # No conversion done internally

You are actually inserting a string, not a float

You should be able to insert floats with `c.enter_data(24.3)`

To debug further I suggest:

- Trying the commands on the mongo command line client, to confirm floating point behavior
- When you insert in the CLI or your Python code, get a hold of the ID of the inserted object, to make sure you are looking at the right object

Comment: I just realized there is a problem in the question. In the first code segment the last line is: c.enter_data(24.3) not  c.enter_data("24.3"). I changed that while checking with integers and strings and forgot to change it  back to orignal form while posting it here.

Comment: As I said I've worked with MOngoJava and CLI they behave perfectly. Even Pymongo behaves perfectly on a intel computer using Ubuntu but when it comes to Raspbian the behaviour changes. It may be because of limited floating point support or of a deprecated mongoDB version (The binaries for the latest version are not available for ARM). In anycase I'll try it with rpi2 and keep you update. Regards

Comment: Apparently it's not working with rpi2 either. When I insert a float from rpi to a remote database then it works just fine. When the object is queried on the computer it was posted to it is displayed as it should be: { "_id" : ObjectId("557d828b08139add2323aeaf"), "A" : 12.1 } but when queried from rpi it displays as: { "_id" : ObjectId("557d828b08139add2323aeaf"), "A" : 0.04667261646131403e-60 }